# how to run hadoop with external jar?

Tags: java, hadoop, jar

I'm going to run my map reduce project on Hadoop 2.9.0. I'm using xml-rpc package in my project as follow:

```
import org.apache.xmlrpc.*;
```

I put additional jars into lib folder and When I ran my project jar in Hadoop, It shows this error:

> Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient

I executed this command:

```
bin/hadoop jar MRV.jar SumMR /user/hadoop/input /user/hadoop/output -libjars lib/xmlrpc-2.0.1.jar: lib/commons-codec-1.10.jar
```

How to execute this command without error of `ClassNotFoundException` ?

Comment: Lookup how you can shade your JAR files using Maven/Gradle

Comment: Anyway, I think should introduce the jars path at runtime.

Comment: Sure, and shading is the easiest way to do it so you're not managing a bunch of different jars

Answer (score 0):

private static void addJarToDistributedCache
(Class classToAdd, Configuration conf)
 throws IOException {

```
// Retrieve jar file for class2Add
String jar = classToAdd.getProtectionDomain().
        getCodeSource().getLocation().
        getPath();
File jarFile = new File(jar);

// Declare new HDFS location
Path hdfsJar = new Path("/user/hadoopi/lib/"
        + jarFile.getName());

// Mount HDFS
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);

// Copy (override) jar file to HDFS
hdfs.copyFromLocalFile(false, true,
    new Path(jar), hdfsJar);

// Add jar to distributed classPath
DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(hdfsJar, conf);
```

}

Comment: Thanks for response. `String jar` in your code is path of my `.classes`. I added library and wanna know path of it.